# Symfony2 Passing ajax request data to a form rendering controller

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, forms, symfony

I have a problem with a Symfony Form which I want to prefill based on which record is viewed beforehand. The intention is to create a means for changing the record data.
I navigate to the form page via javascript and send an ajax request to the same controller the form is rendered by.

This is part of the page used for viewing records:

```
    <input type="button" id="changeRecord" value="change"/>

    record id: <div id="recordID"> {{ record_id }} </div>
```

I access the record id through javascript/jQuery like this:

```
    var CssSelectors = new Array(
        "recordID"
    );

    function getCurrentRecordID() {
        return parseInt($.trim($("#" + CssSelectors[0]).text()));
    };
```

The button-code in javascript is the following:

```
    $('#changeRecord').click(function () {
        window.location.replace(Routing.generate(recordChangeRoute));

        $.ajax({
            url: Routing.generate(recordChangeAjaxRoute),
            type: "POST",
            data: {'recordID': getCurrentRecordID()}
    });
    // both Routes point to the same controller
    // problem located here ???
```

The Symfony Controller Action is the following:

```
public function changePlasmidRecordAction(Request $request) {
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $recordHandle = $em->getRepository('DataBundle:RecordClass');

    $AjaxRequest = Request::createFromGlobals();
    $RecordID = $AjaxRequest->request->get('recordID');

    $recordToUpdate = $recordHandle->findOneBy(array('id' => $RecordID));
    $updateForm = $this->createForm(new RecordClassType(), $recordToUpdate);
    $updateForm->handleRequest($request);

    if ($updateForm->isValid()) {
        $em->flush();
        return this->redirect($this->generateUrl('route_showRecord'));

    } else {
        return $this->render('DataBundle:RecordClass:updateRecord.html. twig',  
        array(
            'RecordID' => $RecordID,
            'form' => $updateForm->createView()
        ));
    }
}
```

What I am trying to achieve is:

- view a record
- go to prefilled form
- make changes and save

Viewing records, creating the form, persisting the changes to the database - all work. What does not work is accessing the needed ID inside the controller.
I can access the ajax request data the way I try in an other controller action without problems.
How is the "Form Request" interfering? Or is it?
Do I have to use an Event Listener?

Any help is greatly appreciated, thanks in advance!

Comment: I reckon `recordId` is a placeholder used only in this question? In real life it will start with `[a-z]` followed by a id number?

Comment: recordId is the "variable name" used to access the data sent to the server. It will contain an integer. It is created in the ajax function.

Comment: Setting an integer as ID-attribute will not work, it needs to have a letter (a-z) as first character.

Comment: This is strange because it does work like this in another case in the same project inside the same controller - send the id integer fetched from html via ajax to controller, query the database, send some response back.

Comment: Why are you creating $AjaxRequest?  Seems like $recordID = $request->request->get('recordID')  would work.

Comment: I just tried that, but it does not work either.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by leaving the ajax stuff away and submitting the required data via GET. Like so:

```
    $('#changeRecord').click(function () {
    window.location.replace(Routing.generate(recordChangeRoute, {'recordID': getCurrentRecordID()}));
    });
```

Thank you for your input, all the best.

Comment: Using GET to change a record is a very bad idea.  All kinds of things can go wrong when you violate HTTP protocol.  Might be better to use a tool like firebug to see that is actually being passed between your browser and the server and get your ajax POST request working properly.